Re-sign-in to VS Code using Github instead of Microsoft
I recently got started with Visual Studio Code, and I'm really enjoying it. At first, I signed in with my Microsoft account from the sign in to sync >sign in with Microsoft/GitHub menu, but I want to log out and change to my GitHub account instead.
If I click Sign Out, it will sign me out, but when I click on Sign In again, it auto-redirects me to the Microsoft login as far as I've experienced.
I may be able to do it by reinstalling VS Code, but I don't really want to go through the setup process and uninstall/reinstall stuff.
Is this possible?
I also noticed here that 'you can also link a GitHub account to a new or existing Microsoft account.' If this is the correct way to do this (or is what I'm trying to ask), then how can I do that?

I've got the same issue in code-1.95.3-1731513157.el8.x86_64 when trying to switch from GitHub to Microsoft. I'm amazed that this apparently hasn't been reported at their GitHub repository as a tracked issue.

Solved it: Here's how I did it:

Sign out through sidebar>accounts>(account)>sign out

Through menu bar commands (Shift-Cmd-P), Settings Sync: Turn Off

sidebar>accounts>backup_and_sync_settings

Select items to sync (in my case, all)

Select 'Sign In'

Select from Github or Microsoft



Worked for me, let me know if you fare differently.
